# How do I purchase a steam game while still on the trial period?

Tags: steam

I am currently on a trial period for a game on steam, and I really enjoy it and want to buy it. However, it is on a huge sale right now and I would love to purchase for that price before the sale ends. I am worried that once the trial ends, so will the sale, and I will not be able to buy it for the price currently listed. So, I guess my question is, how do I purchase the full game BEFORE the free trial ends? (if it's possible that is.)

Answer (score 2):

There should be an "Add to Cart' button below the "Play Game" button on the game's store page:

[image: Excerpt from Steam store page for Shadow of Mordor, showing Play Game and Add to Cart buttons]

If the game you're talking about happens to be Shadow of Mordor, the game shown in the image above, then it appears that the sale goes one for more day (until the 10th) after the trial ends in two days (on the 9th).

Comment: But that's for the package, not the base game itself. I think that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The base game for Shadow of Mordor is no longer available for sale.